# Find semantics words between different phrases

Tags: php, algorithm, semantics

I try to find a way to define in PHP a semantic by comparing some phrases and find occurence for example i have something like

```
Array
(

    [0] => Cats love Mouse Car Dog Fish
    [1] => Pictures Cats Some Text Mouse
    [2] => Game of thrones 2015 Series 
    [3] => Stark Series lannister John Game of thrones
    [4] => Pop Rock David Bowie Music
    [5] => David Great Lower Text Bowie

)
```

And I expected for the output

```
Array
(

    [0] => Cats Mouse
    [1] => Game of thrones Series
    [2] => David Bowie 

)
```

How can I proceed ?

Comment: But how do you will know what are you searching?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins nothing for the moment I m trying to find a solution to do that 
I m looking in 'Latent semantic analysis' but i dont know if it s a good solution

Comment: Why is "Car Dog Fish" not your expected output?  Why is Pictures Text not?

Comment: In other words, you have imbued some of these words with a magical "semantic meaning", but you haven't described in any way how or why.